# How to call angular factory after another is finished?

Tags: angularjs

How to call another angular factory after first factory http call is finished?

First factory:

```
app.factory('personService', function ($http,$rootScope) {    
  return {
    getPerson: function () {
      //return the promise directly.
      return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/emobile/api/rest/confperson/1/1').then(function (result) {
        //resolve the promise as the data
        $rootScope.userLanguage = result.data.person.languageAbbrevation;
        return result.data;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Second factory which needs to be called after first is finished:

```
app.factory('TranslateData', function ($http,$rootScope) {

  return {
    getTranslation: function () {
      //return the promise directly.
      return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/emobile/api/rest/gettranslations/1/1/' + $rootScope.userLanguage).then(function (result) {
        //resolve the promise as the data
        return result.data;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly returning a promise (this is the result of `$http`) from both of those methods. All you need to do now is chain them.

```
personService.getPerson()
  .then(function(personResult){
     return TranslateData.getTranslation();
  })
  .then(function(translationResult){
     // do something after translation
  });
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/imsSeWVARGRHCAhgH8Eh?p=preview) with `$timeout` (which also returns a promise) to illustrate.

And this is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) of `$q` about chaining promises, and [kriskowal/q's](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) - which Angular's `$q` was inspired by.

Comment: Are you sure it will work? I have a feeling that you are calling two different handlers for the same `getPerson()` promise.

Comment: The second `.then` will be called strictly after the completion of the `TranslateData.getTranslation()` promise.

Comment: Can you back it up with some example? I'm not trolling, I'm really not sure if this works like that and I would be very surprised if it would.

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman, then you are "underusing" promises' full potential if this surprises you. Updated the answer with an example.

Comment: you can't learn everything instantly, you know :) Thanks! This really works like you have described and indeed there is a note in the documentation about it. Not sure how I missed that, perhaps it has been updated after I read it. Regardless, thank you for spreading the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is usually referred to as "chaining promises".

I wouldn't usually recommend that, as this leads to a code which:

- is hard to maintain (you couple two services together)
- not efficient - you could run those calls in parallel and therefore obtain the results from server faster
- looks ugly :-)

Based on my experience, usually the best and most efficient way is to prepare all the needed data on the server (therefore have one HTTP calls instead of two).
If that's not possible, then I prefer to create a service which caches promises to `gettranslations` resource and favor that whenever appropriate.

Hard to tell you more without look into the full code, but that's my first impression. If you really want to do that, though, then you can always call:

```
personService.getPerson().success(funciton() {

  // When first call finished, then start the 2nd one

  TranslateData.getTranslation().success(function(){

     // Both calls have finished at this point.

  });

});
```

Comment: Preparing everything on the server is not always possible or desirable. Otherwise, chaining is needed if stepN relies on data from stepN-1. If one wants to parallelize, there is `$q.all`. And finally, Angular is heavily relying on promises; why one would want to avoid it is beyond me.

Comment: Not avoiding using promises, but avoiding extensive use of chaining promises. When dealing with RESTful APIs, this very often means that you are using the API wrong or it wasn't tailored to meet your demands. Therefore I always advice to rethink using chaining for subsequent HTTP calls. As for regular promises (not related to HTTP), of course there is nothing wrong with chaining.